# How do I add custom hyperlinks to a webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to add a hyperlink to a social bookmarking site om my webpage which requires me to include the name of the page it is being sent from.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

Current page is:

http://www.testpage.com/testpage.aspx?test=34

Hyperlink I want to create on the above page:

http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://www.testpage.com/testpage.aspx?test=34

What is the easiest way to programmatically add this customised hyperlink to a webpage?

Comment: We Can't connect to http://www.testpage.com/testpage.aspx?test=34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a hyperlink like that :

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="myLink" Text="stumbleupon"></asp:HyperLink>
```

At server side :

```
string currentPagesUrl = 
       HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
myLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url={0}",  
    currentPagesUrl);
```

Or an alternative way (this one is easier I think) :

```
<a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<%= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) %>" target="_blank">
    stumbleupon 2</a>
```

Comment: Shouldn't HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri be url encoded?

Answer (score 2):

I second Canavar's answer. You might want to also URL encode the currentPagesUrl string when building the hyperlink:

```
myLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url={0}",
    Server.UrlEncode(currentPagesUrl));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.stumblethis").each(function(){
          $(this).attr("href", "http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url="+$(this).attr("href"));
        });    
});
```

This will convert all links that have a class of "stumblethis".

Comment: Cost a lot (looping through every node in document), and doesn't work with client that doesn't support javascript, that's why you get my -1

Comment: @Clement-Herreman:

**(1)** Yes, it won't work if they do not have javascript but the question does not specify that javascript can't be used.


**(2)** jQuery can make use of the browser provided functions getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName to efficiently find just the right elements.